# Is there an easy method to determine if a graph is planar or not?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

[image]

So, I have this graph and I can't find a subgraph that is K5 or K3,3 to use the kuratowski theorem .Is there another way to determine if it is not planar without coloring?

Comment: Have you checked the [known algorithms for that?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planarity_testing)

Comment: $BCGF$ is $K_4$. Maybe you could manipulate the other vertices to make it into a $K_5$ minor?

Comment: @ClementC. I haven't checked them.I guess I will start with that.

Comment: @Arthur The problem is that in my opinion this method doesn't need knowledge or skills .It's just how much time you spend on it. So that's why I am asking for a "clever" easy way.So I am asking for all the complicated graphs that I can't easily find subgraphs that are kuratowski graphs.

Comment: @Mitsos: Do you know the difference between a **subgraph** of a graph and a **minor** of a graph? If not, look it up and re-check Kuratowski's Theorem: what does it say, exactly?

Comment: @Moritz I didn't know the difference (though I guessed it), but it appears that [Kuratowski Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski's_theorem) talks about subgraphs, and the theorem that talks about minors is [Wagner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner's_theorem), according to Wikipedia. Here is also Wikipedia's entry for a [minor of a graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor) (which is not exactly like a quotient, which was my first guess). Thank you, I learned something.

Comment: Kuratowski's theorem talks about subgraphs that are *subdivisions* of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$. This is the same as being able to contract edges of a subgraph to arrive at $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the induced subgraph on $BCFG$ is $K_4$, and all of these vertices have edges leaving them that are not contained in the induced subgraph. Thus contracting all the edges of the (connected) induced subgraph on $ADEH$ gives a single vertex that is connected to all vertices in the $K_4$ on $BCFG$. Thus you arrive at a $K_5$ minor, so the graph cannot be planar.